# calculating the clicks when the banner is clicked

Tags: php

Hi my family and I hope help me.

I have php site 
and it is showing banners and thats calcualtion the impressions only for that banners.
Now I want add banners and calcualte the clicks only for this banner

```
$doing_spots=1;

while($adsetting_temp[banner_spot] >= $doing_spots) 
{

    $bannerads=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads where banner='1' and expired='0' and active='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"));

    $displaybannerad="<a href='$bannerads[link]' target='_blank' ><img src='$bannerads[info]'width='468' height='60'></a>";

    mysql_query("update ads set impdone=impdone+1, active='1' where id=$bannerads[id]");

    if ($bannerads[impdone]+1 >= $bannerads[impbought]) { 
           mysql_query("update ads set expired=1 where id=$bannerads[id]");
    }

    if ($bannerads[id] == '') {
        $displaybannerad="<a href='$adsetting_temp[defaultlink]' target='_blank'><img src='$adsetting_temp[defaultbanner]'alt='$bannerads[info]' width='468' height='60'></a>";
    }

    $template->assign("bannerad$doing_spots",$displaybannerad);

    $doing_spots++;
}
```

how i can do this?
Regards

Comment: 1) Be sure to add quotes around array indexes, `$arr[name]` is wrong, while `$arr['name']` is correct. 2) The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). 3) Your code is prone to SQL injection; check out prepared statements.

Comment: are you can fixed my code ?

Comment: are you can ficed my code? what is your offer?

Comment: No, those were just some comments I had while passing by. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the link on the banner ad to `$bannerads['link']`.  Instead, set all links of your banners to go to a single route, something along the lines of `http://domain/outbound?ad={ad id}`

In your new route, determine what ad was directed to it. Update its number of clicks to +1 and then simply send a header redirect back to the client to send them to `$bannerads['link']`.